# How can I send an email with attachement using the API MailJet in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, email, nsmutableurlrequest, mailjet

**FIRST ERROR**

I use this code but I don't know how to use the api Mailjet in iOS ? Where to put the API key private, the public etc...
I check the [github](https://github.c) mailjet, the [doc](https://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/) mailJet about the API without success.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSLog(@"File Size: %lu",(unsigned long)[data length]);

//set up request
NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//required xtra info
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//body of the post
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"thefile\"; filename=\"recording\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postbody];
NSURLConnection *apiConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I do tests with sending "manually", and I have that bad answer. Where I have to put the API KEY and the SECRET KEY ?[image]

**EDIT**
**SECOND ERROR**

New code :

```
        NSString *apiKey = @"*******************";
        NSString *secretKey = @"**************";
        NSString *mail = @"******@******.***";

        // Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.
        NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_params setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"ver"];
        [_params setObject:@"en" forKey:@"lan"];
        [_params setObject:apiKey forKey:@"apiKey"];
        [_params setObject:secretKey forKey:@"secretKey"];

        // the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
        NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------***********";

        // string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
        NSString* FileParamConstant = @"file";

        // the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
        NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send/"];

        // create request
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        //HTTP Basic Authentication
        NSString *authenticationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", apiKey, secretKey];
        NSData *authenticationData = [authenticationString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64Encoding];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authenticationValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        // set Content-Type in HTTP header
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@"application/json"; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
        [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        [request addValue:apiKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"apiKey"] ;
        [request addValue:secretKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"secretKey"] ;

        // post bodyv
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        // add params (all params are strings)
        for (NSString *param in _params) {
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }

        // add image data
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
        if (imageData) {
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; FromEmail:\"contact@****.fr\"; \"Text-part\":\"Dear\" ; Recipients:[{\"Email\":\"****@gmail.com\"}]; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:imageData];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // set the content-length
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        // set URL
        [request setURL:requestURL];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@, error: %@", requestReply, error);
        }] resume];
```

New error message:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
- (void) sendToMail:(NSString *)mailingList

{

    NSString *filePath = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:STATS_FILE];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    mailingList = MAILING_LIST;



    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])

    {

        // Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.

        NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [_params setObject:@"xxxx@xxxx.xxx" forKey:@"FromEmail"];

        [_params setObject:@"xxx xxx xxxx" forKey:@"FromName"];

        [_params setObject:@"xxx xxx xxx" forKey:@"Subject"];

        [_params setObject:@"xxx xxxx xxxx" forKey:@"Html-part"];

        //mail(s) treatment

        NSUInteger numberOfOccurrences = [[mailingList componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] count] - 1;

        NSArray *subStrings = [mailingList componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

        NSMutableArray *mailsArr = [NSMutableArray new];



        for (int i=0; i<=numberOfOccurrences; i++)

        {

            NSString *mail = [subStrings objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([self validEmail:mail])

               [mailsArr addObject:@{@"Email":mail}];

        }



        if ([mailsArr count] > 0)

           [_params setObject:mailsArr forKey:@"Recipients"];



        //add any attachment file to JSON

        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        if (data)

        {

            NSString *encodedString = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

            NSArray *attachmentsArr = @[@{@"Content-type":@"text/plain", @"Filename":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.db", [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]], @"content":encodedString}];

            [_params setObject:attachmentsArr forKey:@"Attachments"];

        }



        // the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here

        NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send/"];



        // create request

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

        [request setTimeoutInterval:30];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



        //HTTP Basic Authentication

        NSString *authenticationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", API_KEY, SECRET_KEY];

        NSData *authenticationData = [authenticationString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSString *authenticationValue = [authenticationData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", authenticationValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];



        NSString *jsonRequest = [_params JSONRepresentation];

        NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", jsonRequest);



        NSMutableData *requestData = [[jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



        // setting the body of the post to the request

        [request setHTTPBody:requestData];



        // set the content-length

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestData length]];

        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        [request setURL:requestURL]; // set URL



        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

#if DEBUG

            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@, error: %@", requestReply, error);

#endif

            if (error == nil)

            {

                [self showAlertWithMessage:@"File sent!" withButton:@"Ok!"];

            }

            else

            {

                [self showAlertWithMessage:@"Could not send file!" withButton:@"Ok!"];

            }

        }] resume];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm leading the API at Mailjet.

Few things to note in your post:

- It seems your call lacks a Basic Authentification, see [Postman documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers) for more details on about to set it. You can fetch your API credentials [here](https://app.mailjet.com/account/api_keys)
- You use a `form-data` `Content-Type` while our API only supports `application/json` as input format. Please refer to our [API guides](https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#send-transactional-email) for more details about the payload to send us
- You do not seem to provide your API credentials in the objective-c code you provided. Same than in the first point, you can fetch them from [here](https://app.mailjet.com/account/api_keys)

We do not officially support iOS with Objective-C or Swift, apologies for the inconvenience.

Hope it helps

Thanks for having chosen Mailjet to power your emails!

Comment: I put the Basic Authentification, it works. But now, I have a different error message now: 400 at least "to" value required. (I edited my code for info in the ticket)

Comment: Et merci pour votre réponse rapide le vendredi :D

Comment: @Claudio, my pleasure ;). The JSON you put in Recipients is not a valid one it seems. It should be `[{"Email": "test@gmail"}]`. The issue is not the single quote `'` but the use of comma `,` as the key/value separator instead of semi-colon `:`. Also, I would recommend doing tests with your own email address since test@gmail.com will mostly lead to a bounce.

Comment: Hi, for the mail, it was just for the ticket. I avoid to put the real mail, we never know. I am progressing, I just succeeded in sending email to my mail. The only thing is missing is to add an attachment, and I will put the final answer. Thank you for your support :D

Comment: Great, glad it works! The related API guide for attachments is here: https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#sending-with-attached-files

Please, don't forget to accept my answer so other can refer to it if they're running in the same issue than you in the future. 
Thanks for having chosen Mailjet to power your email!